# Finding examples of continuous functions

Tags: analysis, functions, continuity

I'm looking for
1) a function that is discontinuous at 0, 1, 1/2, 1/3, 1/4, 1/5, ... but continuous everywhere else
2) a function that is discontinuous at 1, 1/2, 1/3, /4, 1/5, ... but continuous everywhere else.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: 1) Modify $f(x)=1$ appropriately. 2) Modify $f(x)=x$ appropriately.

Comment: You could really just define $f$ by $f(x) = 0$ whenever $x \in \{ 1/n : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ and $f(x) = 1$ whenever $x$ is not in that set.

Comment: Does this mean you are requiring that $f(x)$ be continuous for all $x < 0$?

Comment: @shoover : I guess "everywhere else" includes $x<0$

Comment: @user88595 I guessed so too, but it's nice to have it clarified since the domain of $x$ wasn't specified.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathbb{N}=\{1,2,\dots\}$ and define

$$f(x)= \left\{ \begin{array}{rl} 0, & x=1/n \text{ for some } n\in \mathbb{N} \\
  x, & \text{ elsewhere.} \end{array} \right.$$

Answer (score 0):

HINT :
Whenever you want a function to be discontinuous at $a$, divide by $(x-a)$.

Repeat the process for every discontinuity.

OR, if you want it to exist at discontinuity then something like :
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}1 \qquad \forall \, x\in \mathbb R \backslash E\\ 0 \qquad \forall \, x \in E\end{cases}$$

where $E$ is the set where you want it to be discontinuous.

Comment: Well, then the function is not even defined at $a$.

Comment: But you can set it to be, say, 5 at a.

Comment: It's not stated in the question it should necessarily exist.

Comment: if $f$ is discontinuous at $a$, then this means by definition that there exists an $\epsilon > 0$ such that for all $\delta > 0$, we can find $x$ in the domain of $f$ with $|x-a| < \delta$ but $|f(x) - f(a)| \geq \epsilon$. For this to make sense, the number $f(a)$ must be defined.

Comment: @Svinepels : I get your points. Continuity means the limit on both sides of $x_0$ equal $f(x_0)$ with $f(x_0)$ defined. Clearly as you said here it's not defined therefore my proposed function is not continuous.

Comment: Now does "not continuous" and "discontinuous" mean the same? I actually never thought about this.

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)=\dfrac1{\{1/x\}}$ would be one such example.